# How do I change the count of an array?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, polycount

I used to be able to change the count - which I set to 30 - and I wanted to change it to 12, but I don't see an option for it anymore:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

if you already applied your modifier, you cannot change it afterwards. As long as you don't apply the modifier you can change it.

e.g.:

green: not applied modifier

red : applied modifier

[image]

[image]